# How to use '>>' in popen subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to run the command from a python file (2.7):

```
p=subprocess.Popen("sha256sum file1.zip >> file2.sha")
```

But i got an error that file '>>' does not exist.
I tried:

```
p=subprocess.Popen("sha256sum file1.zip >> file2.sha".split())
```

But still the `>>` is a problem.

Of course that if I run the command in the prompt line it run Ok and put the output into the file file2.sha.

I know I can add stdout to the Popen but I was wonder if there is a way to run it as simple as runing from the command line.

Thanks.

Comment: you get an error because you are trying to use Popen like it was os.system(). Have a look into documentation how Popen works: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass values for the stdin and stdout of the child process to Popen like so:

```
subprocess.Popen("sha256sum file1.zip", stdout = file("file2.sha", "a"))
```

Note the file needs to be opened in append mode to achieve the same behaviour as >>.

Comment: Thanks Ben. warwaruk answer also worked but I read that it can cause a security problem using "shall" with input from the user (It get a file name) so I will use stdout instead.

Comment: To make it more explicit when the file is closed in the parent process, you could use `with`-statement: `with open('file2.sha', 'ab') as file: subprocess.check_call(["sha256sum", "file1.zip"], stdout=file)`

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use [`shell=True` argument](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) to `Popen`:

> If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the
>   shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the
>   enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want
>   convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes,
>   filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of ~
>   to a user’s home directory.

```
subprocess.Popen("sha256sum file1.zip >> file2.sha", shell=True)
```